# make a group in report.rdlc as shown in screenshot

Tags: c#, report, grouping, rdlc

as shown in this screenshot there is a column group

[image: Column Group]

now what I want to do is this

[image]

Is there any way to do this in report.rdlc ?

I will be grateful for any help

Comment: Can't you just put two tables together without a gap.

Comment: @jdweng so I'm going with classic print document tools.. Thanks so much